# Testing File system Full scenario

Tags: linux

I have a program that writes files to disk. I want to test  the programs behaviour when the filesystem written to is full.

What is the best option for creating a small filesystem to test this without having to order disk setup which on the SAN... I guess [Ram disk](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Ramdisk/ramdisk.html) requires reboots which is not great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop device sounds good. You can dd to a file, and then make an fs on the file, and loop mount it for testing. You can even simulate partitions. http://www.andremiller.net/content/mounting-hard-disk-image-including-partitions-using-linux

Answer (score 6):

You should use /dev/full as it is made available just for that.
/dev/full is virtual device that is always full.

```
$ echo "Hello world" > /dev/full
bash: echo: write error: No space left on device
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/full